# Probability of system working using conditional probabilities

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, inclusion-exclusion

A system consists of components 1, 2, 3, and 4 that work with probability p1, p2, p3, and p4 respectively. The signal can only pass through a component if it is working. The components are independent of each other. The system works if a signal can pass from S to E. What is the probability that the system works? [Image of system architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZ308.png)

I know that the probability is $P(\text{system works})= P( (1 \cap 4) \cup (1 \cap 3) \cup (2 \cap 3 \cap 4) \cup 2) =  P( (1 \cap 4) \cup (1 \cap 3) \cup 2)$. Using the [inclusion–exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), this probability can be calculated. However, if the diagram gets more complicated its quite messy to calculate the probability using this approach.

This is a slightly simplified problem from the chapter about conditional probabilities from Ross' textbook "Introduction to Probability models". Thus, I assume there is a simpler way to calculate the above probability using conditioning. So my question is if and how the probability of the system working can be calculated using conditional probabilities.

Comment: "*If the diagram gets more complicated its quite messy to calculate*"  This is true of any approach.  I have no great advice to give beyond what you already seem to know... that depending on circumstance, the desired event can sometimes be written more cleanly, but how to see it or how to take advantage of it and whether it even conveys any noticeable benefit varies greatly.